# why does the formula for the radius of convergence $R^{-1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ valid here?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Suppose we have the series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. How do I find the radius of convergence?

My attempt

I used the Ratio test. I got the R=1.

But in the textbook author used the formula $R^{-1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|2n+3|}{|2n+1|}=1.$ I don't understand how can he justify the usage of this Radius of convergence formula for the power series. The above series is a power series with the coefficient of even powers zero. Could you help me in the justification?

Comment: Note that $|x|^2 < 1$ if and only if $|x| < 1$.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain more?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{y^{n}}{2n+1}$ with $y=x^2$.

Comment: The suggestion in the textbook is not always efficient. For example $\sum a_nx^{n^2}$ the $n$th root or the ratio test may be effective but no substitution is possible.

Comment: Can there exist a case where this suggestion fail?